# Sort by given index sequence using Stream

Tags: java, android, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Im trying think if this sorting by index is possible using **streams**. 
All my searches always point to sorting by comparing object value into other object value. 
***Below is the example data and the expected results :***

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
movies.add(new Movie(1, "Movie1"));
movies.add(new Movie(2, "Movie2"));
movies.add(new Movie(3, "Movie3"));
movies.add(new Movie(4, "Movie4"));

int[] sortIndex = [0, 3, 1, 2];
...Sorting Code...
for (Movie movie : movies) {
    Log.d(TAG, movie.getName());
}
```

Expected answer should be

```
Movie1
Movie4
Movie2
Movie3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is iterate over the `Array`, and then map each int to the corresponding index of the `List`, and then collect that to a `List`:

```
List<Movie> newList = Arrays.stream(sortIndex)
                            .mapToObj(e -> movies.get(e))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which will produce the `List`:

```
[Movie1, Movie4, Movie2, Movie3]
```

You can create a method to do this:

```
public <T> List<T> sortList(int[] sortOrder, List<T> list) {
    return Arrays.stream(sortOrder)
                 .mapToObj(e -> list.get(e))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Will give a try for this one.